# Flutter: How to keep Bluetooth connection active even on terminated state for iOS apps

Tags: ios, flutter, bluetooth-lowenergy, background-process, ancs

So, me and my team are trying to create a bluetooth connection between iOS devices and an external device using Flutter.
In our app we have to maintain a stable bluetooth connection (at all times) between the app and an external device even if the app is terminated. I know that for Android, this can be achieved with background services using a plugin like [background_fetch](https://pub.dev/packages/background_fetch) but iOS doesn't offer background services when the app is terminated and the only way to keep the bluetooth connection active when the app is terminated is by using **Apple Notification Center Service**
Is there a package or a recommended way to keep bluetooth connection active on a terminated iOS app? If not, is there any documentation on how to create a Flutter wrapper around ANCS native iOS code?

Comment: It is just not possible to keep a connection when your app is terminated, because it isn't running. The only reason your app should be terminated if you have an active Bluetooth connection is Bluetooth background permission is if the user has swiped your app away.  If the user swiped it away then they explicitly don't want your app running.  You can use Bluetooth State Restoration to relaunch your app when your peripheral is discovered or connectable again.  This is important anyway because the connection can be lost at any time.

Comment: ANCS is used for external devices to connect *to* an iOS device in order to receive notifications. The connection isn't to your app.

Comment: @Paulw11 I know about that. Is there a way to write a flutter wrapper to receive ANCS notifications on flutter?

Comment: @Paulw11 Or at least a way to launch the Flutter app when ANCS receives specific notifications?

Comment: You want to write a Flutter app to connect to the ANCS service on another iOS device? Such an app would need to stay connected to the ANCS service. It can't be launched with the NS sends a specific notification.

Comment: What I want to do is create a flutter app that runs on iOS and connects to a wearable device. Since keeping the bluetooth connection active in the terminated state is impossible...I'm thinking of how to use ANCS with Flutter (on the same iOS device) so that when the wearable device sends notifications, ANCS will catch them and then ANCS will do something to launch The flutter app (ANCS sends native push notification for example, when the user taps on that notification...It will open the Flutter app). I don't know if it's doable like this.

Comment: That's not how ANCS works. A device, such as a wearable, connects to the ANCS service on iOS and receives notifications from the iOS device. Your device would act as a notification client. The iOS device is the notification server.  Devices don't send notifications to iOS.  iOS sends notifications to devices.  You will need to write native code to manage your connection via Core Bluetooth and integrate this with Flutter as a plug-in.

Comment: Then, I guess you can send notifications (write bluetooth characteristic with a waiting for response) from the phone (iOS) to the wearable device and then the device will respond so that ANCS can do something on the iPhone...example, shows a push notification on the phone, when the user taps that push notification it opens the Flutter app.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245723/discussion-between-paulw11-and-samir-ait-abdelkoui).